# i need help locating an infinite loop i have

Tags: c++, loops

Can't find where the loop is can someone help locate it

It looks to me that all the loops close.

I'm supposed to use a for loop to print out a vertical bar graph but it seems to be looping

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int MAX=100;
    int array[MAX];
    int highest=0;

    for (int counter=0; counter<MAX; counter++) {

        cin>>array[counter];

        if(array[counter]==0){

            for (int check=0; check<=counter; check++) {
                if(array[check]>highest)
                    highest=array[check];
            }

            for (int rows=highest;rows>=1;rows--) {
                for (int cols=0; cols<=26; cols++) {
                    if (array[cols]>=rows)
                        cout<<"* ";
                    else
                        cout<<"  ";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `for (int i = 0; i < 1 ; i++)`?

Comment: Time to learn how to debug your program.

Comment: What do you think `int array[100]; int highest = array[0];` will actually save in `highest` when you've set *nothing* in `array[0]` yet. Its content is *indeterminate*. You program is ill-formed and invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: For what it's worth, your first inner loop (to find `highest`) seems to be equivalent to `std::max_element`.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of places where you are using uninitialized values.

1. Change

   ```
   int highest = array[0]; // array[0] is uninitialized
   ```

to

```
    int highest = 0;
```

2. Change

   ```
       for(int find = 0;find<=25;find++) // Not all elements of
                                         // array have been initialized.
   ```

to

```
        for(int find = 0;find<=counter;find++)
```

I can't vouch for the logical validity of other pieces of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Among the things wrong in your code:

- You initialize `highest` with an indeterminate value.
- Your output branch is only taken if someone inputs `0`, not if someone inputs 25 actual numbers.
- You never **validate input** of any given value actually *succeeded*
- The limits of your output loops are wrong. You can (and will) evaluate content in `array[]` that is indeterminate if the input loop is prematurely terminated with a `0` input value.
- The `i < 1` loop is completely unnecessary.
- Calculation of `highest` can/should be done *during* input; it need not be done after.
- You should be using *unsigned* values. None of this should permit input of negative numbers.

Taking all of the above into account.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int arr[25] = {0}, highest=0;
    int len = 0;

    for (; len < 25 && std::cin >> arr[len] && arr[len] > 0; ++len)
    {
        if (highest < arr[len])
            highest = arr[len];
    }

    while (highest--)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
            std::cout << ((highest < arr[i]) ? '*' : ' ') << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Input**

```
12 5 7 11 6 9 4 8 10 2 0
```

**Output**

```
*                   
*     *             
*     *         *   
*     *   *     *   
*     *   *   * *   
*   * *   *   * *   
*   * * * *   * *   
* * * * * *   * *   
* * * * * * * * *   
* * * * * * * * *   
* * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * *
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected program:

1. I have declared a macro **MAX** to set the number to 25 so that i
   could debug with a lesser number.
2. The equality case has been removed in <=25 as it is not entered by
   user
3. I have initialized the array with all 0s for clarity as we dont want
   it to check with garbage value

---

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 25
using namespace std;

int main()  {

    int array[100] = {0,};
    int highest = array[0];
    for (int counter = 0; counter < MAX; counter++){
        cin >> array[counter];
        if (array[counter] == 0){
            for (int i = 0; i <1; i++){
                for (int find = 0; find < MAX; find++){
                    if (array[find]>highest){
                        highest = array[find];
                    }
                }
                for (int rows = highest; rows >= 1; rows--){
                    for (int cols = 0; cols < MAX; cols++){
                        if (array[cols] >= rows){
                            cout << "* ";
                        }
                        else{
                            cout << "  ";
                        }
                    }
                    cout << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int counter = 0; counter < MAX; counter++){
        cout << array[counter] << endl;
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This program does not run infinitely like you claim. It works well. :)